# Упаковка и распаковка типов

Tags: типы, java

Объясните, пожалуйста, самоучке зачем нужны операции упаковки и распаковки типов в Java.

Пример:

```
int value = 238;
Integer boxedValue = Integer.valueOf(value);
```

Код то я полностью понимаю. А вот зачем?

Comment: насколько я помню в java-коллекциях нельзя использовать примитивные типы, дабы обойти это используют классы обёртки ....

Comment: т.е. для этого?

List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
listOfIntegers.add(Integer.valueOf(238));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Философический ответ:

В идеале, в объектно-ориентированном языке - все сущности должны быть объектами. Отец основатель Java - Джеймс Гослинг это прекрасно понимал, но он также и будучи реалистом понимал, что если все сущности сделать объектами язык потеряет в скорости, посему было решено сохранить понятие примитивных типов: `int`, `byte` и проч. и дополнить библиотеку объектов их объектными аналогами: `Integer`, `Byte` и т.д. Естественно была предусмотрена конверсия между примитивными типами и их объектными аналогами.

Начиная с Java 5 конверсия производится автоматически (называется boxing/unboxing)

Вот собственно и все.

Comment: А реальность такая, что не осилили они сделать хороший  int, который компилятор мог хорошо использовать как объект. То есть, что бы выражения `List<int> listOfIntegers;` работали как ожидается (без выделения лишней памяти).

Comment: А кто осилил? От int требуется, чтобы он занимал 4 байта и не больше, от объекта требуется, чтобы в нем была ссылка на тип и/или таблицу методов. То есть, из int нормального объекта не получишь.

Comment: но компилятор может красиво это дело обставить.

Answer (score 4):

Очевидно, что есть методы принимающие/возвращающие значения типа `int` или `Integer`, и иногда нужно преобразовывать примитивы в обертки и наоборот.

Boxing/unboxing начиная с Java 5 производится автоматически. Методы преобразования примитивов в объекты остались для обратной совместимости.

Сам метод `Integer.valueOf(int)` эффективнее, чем конструктор `Integer(int)`, т.к. для заданного диапозона чисел (по умолчанию [-128; 127]) вернет закэшированное значение объекта Integer.

Это, кстати, можно почерпнуть из документации к методу [Integer.valueOf(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29).

Comment: а смысл то в чём заключается? В использовании коллекций, верно?

Comment: @Cyrus Smith Первое предложение ответа вам непонятно? Расшифрую.

Есть метод `int getSmth()` и есть метод `processSmth(Integer value)`.

Если у вас Java младше 1.5, то вы можете сделать так: `processSmth(Integer.valueOf(getSmth()))`.

Коллекции - это лишь частный случай. Общий случай: любое преобразование типа между примитивом и оберткой.