# Основные отличия примитивных типов от непримитивных в Java

Tags: java

`Integer` or `int`.

`Character` or `char`.

Я понимаю и пользуюсь ими когда нужно, но почему так - не знаю.

Comment: Примитивами нельзя конкретизировать генерики `List<int>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Возьмусь предположить, что вы спрашиваете разницу между примитивными типами и классами обертками.

### Примитивные типы

- Выигрыш в производительности.

### Оболочки (обертки) типов

- Являются частью объектной иерархии.
- Необходимы в случаях когда класс может работать только с объектами.
- Удобство использования таких полей как `MAX_VALUE` и.т.д.

**P.S.**
Прекрасный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/252474/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2) о причинах введения автоматической автоупаковки/распаковки.

Answer (score 7):

Непримитивные являются классами, потомками Object. Соответственно, передаются по ссылке. К ним применяются все правила работы с классами и объектами. Это часто бывает нужно, если их нужно передать в качестве аргумента методу, принимающему Object. Или указать в качестве параметра типа для Generic-а. Например, `List<Character>`. Но не может быть `List<char>`.

В свою очередь, примитивные типы передаются по значению. Занимают меньше памяти и лишены при обработке оверхеда объектов. Во многих случаях при присвоении или передаче значения Java конвертирует примитивные типы в их объектные обёртки и обратно автоматически.

Подробнее можно узнать в спецификации языка: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1

EDIT: Важно не путать, что именно мы передаём по значению, а что - по ссылке. Любая переменная ссылочного типа (reference type) хранит в себе ссылку на объект или null, если она не связана с объектом. Так же, как и в случае с переменной примитивного типа, переменная ссылочного типа передаётся по значению. В этом смысле разницы между ними нет.

Однако большая разница возникает, когда думаем о передаче примитива и объекта (или массива).

Передавая примитивное значение, в вызванном методе мы теряем всякую связь с прежней переменной, содержавшей это значение, и никак на неё повлиять не можем.

Однако, передавая ссылку, мы получаем ключ к объекту или массиву, что в общем случае создаёт проблему shared mutable state и может привести к разного рода "сюрпризам", когда объект-владелец переменной внезапно обнаруживает (или даже и не обнаруживает), что значение его атрибута изменилось.

С помощью специальных методик проектирования классов (или специальных библиотек с такими классами) можно добиться того, чтобы однажны созданные экземпляры ссылочных типов было (почти) невозможно изменить. Ключевые слова: immutable type, persistent type, value object. В языках JVM, ориентированных на функциональное программирование, такие типы входят в базовую библиотеку. В самой Java таким образом реализованы, например, обёртки над примитивными типами и String.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. В java все передается по значению, в том числе и ссылочные типы.

Comment: Немножечко [пруфа](http://info.javarush.ru/translation/2014/06/30/Передача-параметров-в-Java-Перевод-.html) к словам @TheNorthon .

Comment: Смотря, что Вы считаете значением. В случае с объектным типом (reference type) в качестве значения передаётся ссылка на объект (reference). Да, значением переменной ссылочного типа также является ссылка на объект - в этом смысле передача происходит по значению. Однако, без специальных ухищрений Вы не получите "из коробки" Value-object, и будете иметь возможность повлиять на состояние переданного объекта. Так что, если мы говорим о передаче объекта - то говорим именно о передаче ссылки на него. В то время как сама переменная объектом не является.

Comment: @iTollu я с Вами согласен, но как мне кажется, не будет лишним указать тот факт, что ссылки на объекты передаются по значению. Это ожидаемо, что ссылочные типы ссылаются на объект и мы получим в методе именно этот объект, а не его копию (мое субъективно мнение, не более). Согласитесь, что ошибиться и присвоить переданной ссылке другой объект, желая обратиться к нему после вызова метода, можно запросто, попутно "отстрелив" себе одну из ног.

Comment: @TheNorthon Спасибо, постарался разъяснить. Наверно, букв получилось многовато.

Answer (score 3):

В Java есть 2 группы типов: ссылочные и примитивные. Примитивных всего 8:

- Целые числа - byte, short, char, int, long.
- Числа с плавающей точкой (иначе дробные) - float, double.
- Логический - boolean.

Остальные типы являются наследниками класса Object и являются ссылочными. Ссылочные передаются в методы(функции) по ссылке, т.е. если вы измените в функции ссылочный тип - то они изменится и в точке вызова (в месте, откуда вы его передали). Примитивные же передаются по значению: т.е. что бы вы не сделали с передаваемым примитивным типом в функции/методе, это всё навсегда останется внутри функции/метода, и снаружи (в точке вызова) он (и его значение) останется таким же после отрабатывания функции.

Подробнее читайте [тут](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85).

Comment: Так себе ответ. Фразу про изменение можно понять двояко. А все перечисленные примитивы иммутабельны. А передачи по ссылки в джаве вообще нет, поэтому в этом плане между ними различия совсем нет.